# How do vending machine Upgrades work?

Tags: borderlands-2

As you cycle through vending machine options in Borderlands 2, there's an Upgrades section that is always empty.  Do items ever appear there?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Note; I have not played through the DLC, there might be some changes that occur in them that I am not aware of.

With that said, If you go to the Eridium Black Market (Crazy Earl's shop in sanctuary), you'll notice all the SDU upgrades are categorized as "Upgrade". The ammunition vending machines having a filter for upgrades is probably a holdover from the first Borderlands game where ammunition SDUs were purchased from these machines.